# Finding the cumulative distribution function of a maximum function, based on a uniform distribution

Tags: statistics, random-variables, uniform-distribution, parameter-estimation, cumulative-distribution-functions

Suppose I have a uniform distribution

$X$ ~ U($0, θ$).

I have an estimator which pertains to the random variable of the largest value among my random sample. We can express this as

max$(X_1, X_2...X_n).$

I'm currently struggling with how to find the CDF for this function and subsequently derive its PDF.

I was thinking of setting

$F(x)$ = $P$(max$(X_1,...X_n)$ $<= x$)

But I'm unsure how to proceed from here.

Any help appreciated!